# Follow a Specific User

Tags: support, feature-request

Say I really like some poster's questions, or another poster's answers. Unfortunately, they post rarely. Is there any way to be alerted (I mean inbox) when they post a new question/answer? A bit like the follow feature of twitter?

Comment: http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/feeds/user/3510 Will this do ?

Comment: In a pinch, though I'd prefer a more graphical solution.

Comment: Yes, I admit it's ugly. Reminds me of Reddit.

Comment: That looks like a standard RSS feed, in which case you can use any RSS feed reader to see it presented nicely.

Comment: For example, it's not super pretty but: http://www.feedbucket.com/?src=http%3A%2F%2Fworldbuilding.stackexchange.com%2Ffeeds%2Fuser%2F3510

Comment: Cool. If you put that in an answer I'll accept it.